# Parse regular expressions with operator precedence parser?

Tags: regex, parsing

is it possible to parse regular expressions with an

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser

If not, what parser is for example used here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson's_construction#Application_of_the_algorithm

Yours sincerely

Comment: May the downvoter at least let me know what I did wrong in his eyes?

Comment: It's a category error. You don't *parse* with regular expressions; all you can do is recognize whether a string matches one. What Thomspon's construction does is turn a regular expression into a NFA; simulating the execution of the NFA will let you decide whether a string is or is not in the language defined by the regular expression. "Parsing" consists of dividing a sentence into *parts*, based on some concrete grammar, usually a context-free grammar. A regular expression is not a grammar in that sense. (Not my downvote, by the way.)

Comment: No it's not a category mistake. I do well know the difference between using regular expressions ("parse *with*") implemented as NFA / subset constructed DFA as a tool represent regular languages on one hand and a **regular expression engine** on the other hand that **constructs** a NFA/DFA from a given regular expression, which then in turn accepts an input as member of this language - or not. 

Im really beginning to get fed up with being intentionally misunderstood and getting to hear "RTFM" this "RTFM" that all the time. Getting downvoted for no reason from people too cowardly to identify

Comment: Maybe my question is stupid. IDK. If you say "von Spotz, your question is stupid", then I will accept this. I just can't see more in Thompson's Algorithm than rules how to represent, say, a (union | expression) as an NFA. How would it be a predictive parsing algorithm. How would it know from an open_paren that only a Kleene star expression could follow? All I know is that It would take a huge amount of lookahead to go to the closing_paren and look what quantitative modifier follows it. (while it's not even clear if the parens do actually match)

I'd be thankful for an explanation.

Comment: To put it simply, the moderator is asking about the process of converting
[0-9]+ into (([((0)-(9))])+). NOT whether it's possible to parse USING regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an [Operator Precedence Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_grammar) for regular expressions, and if that's the case then you can't use an Operator Precedence parser.

Here is a grammar for regular expressions, which I've simplified from [a Perl-style one](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/Teaching/384/99-3/regexp-plg.html):

```
<RE>    ::=     <union> | <simple-RE>
<union>     ::= <RE> "|" <simple-RE>
<simple-RE>     ::=     <concatenation> | <basic-RE>
<concatenation>     ::= <simple-RE> <basic-RE>
<basic-RE>  ::= <star> | <plus> | <elementary-RE>
<star>  ::= <elementary-RE> "*"
<plus>  ::= <elementary-RE> "+"
<elementary-RE>     ::= <group> | <any> | <char>
<group>     ::=     "(" <RE> ")"
<any>   ::=     "."
<char>  ::=     any non metacharacter | "\" metacharacter
```

Notice that `<concatenation>` has two adjacent nonterminals on its right, which means this isn't an Operator Precedence grammar.

I think the method of choice for parsing regular expressions is probably a [Recursive Descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Comment: Thank you very much Martin Broadhurst!

What algorithm is it then that the wikipedia example is using?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson's_construction#Application_of_the_algorithm

Comment: You can't tell from the example because it's showing the constituents being used without indicating how they were derived, so it might have used any parsing algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much. The answer is really much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can indeed be parsed with an operator precedence parser. The supplied C code basically uses a pratt parser (operator precedence) approach. The program prints an NFA (non-deterministic finite automaton) expressed by a series of state transitions. Input is a regular expression with the usual *?()+.[] operators. The pratt parser function *parse()* is first creating an expression tree for the regular expression. It treats two consecutive chars (or parenthesized groups) as if an invisible binary CONCAT operator were between them. After that the function *print_nfa()* traverses the expression tree from right to left and prints the NFA state transitions on the fly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_PREC 10
#define MAX_CHAR 255 // code for chars from 0 to incl. MAX_CHAR

enum Type { CHAR = MAX_CHAR+1, CONCAT, ANY, SET };

typedef unsigned short IType;

struct Node {
    IType type, ch, state;
    struct Node *left, *right;
    char charset[1];
};

static char *regex;
static IType state;
static struct Node *parse(int prec, struct Node *left);

static int next_token(void) { return *regex ? *regex++ : 0; }

struct Node *allocnode(IType type, IType ch, int extra)
{
    struct Node *node = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Node) + extra);
    node->type  = type;
    node->ch    = ch;
    node->state = state++;
    return node;
}

static int getprec(int op) // get the precedence level of op (highest precedence is 0)
{
    switch (op) {
        case '[': case '(': return 0;           // brackets and parenthesis are like literals: highest precedence
        case '*': case '+': case '?': return 1; // postfix operators
        case CONCAT: default: return 2;         // concat
        case '|': return 3;                     // alternate operator is lowest precedence
        case ')': return 4;                     // closing parenthesis is even lower
    }
}

static struct Node *charset(void)
{
    struct Node *node;
    int         i;

    node = allocnode(SET, 0, 1024);

    // scan until end of set
    for (i=0; regex[0] != ']' && regex[0] != '\0'; ++regex, ++i)
        node->charset[i] = regex[0];
    node->charset[i] = '\0';

    if (regex[0] == ']') // eat terminating ]
        ++regex;

    return node;
}

static struct Node *paren(struct Node *left)
{
    struct Node *node = parse(getprec(')'), left);
    if (regex[0] == ')')
        ++regex;

    return node;
}

static struct Node *single(void)
{
    if (regex[-1] == '.')
        return allocnode(ANY, 0, 0);
    else
        return allocnode(CHAR, regex[-1], 0);
}

static struct Node *postfix(int tok, struct Node *left)
{
    struct Node *node = allocnode((IType) tok, 0, 0);
    node->left = left;
    return node;
}

static struct Node *binary(int tok, struct Node *left)
{
    struct Node *node = allocnode((IType) tok, 0, 0);
    node->left = left;
    node->right = parse(getprec(tok) + 1, NULL);
    return node;
}

static struct Node *parse(int prec, struct Node *left)
{
    int tok = next_token();

    // handle prefix
    switch (tok) {
        case '[': left = charset(); break;
        case '(': left = paren(NULL); break;
        case '*': case '+': case '?': break;
        case '|': break;
        case '\0': return left;
        default: left = single(); break;
    }

    // handle infix and postfix operators
    while (*regex && getprec(regex[0]) < prec) {
        tok = next_token();
        switch (tok) {
            case '*': case '+': case '?': left = postfix(tok, left); break;
            case '|': left = binary('|', left); break;

            // concat is like an invisible infix operator (that's why we -- here)
            default: --regex; left = binary(CONCAT, left); break;
        }
    }

    return left;
}

static IType print_nfa(struct Node *root, IType final)
{
    IType temp;

    if (root == NULL)
        return 0;

    switch (root->type) {
        case CONCAT: // build two nfa's that link left-->right
            return print_nfa(root->left, print_nfa(root->right, final));

        case '|':
            // build two nfa's that both link to final: left-->final and right-->final
            // create two epsilon transitions to the two nfa's
            printf("(%d, ε, %d)\n", root->state, print_nfa(root->left, final));
            printf("(%d, ε, %d)\n", root->state, print_nfa(root->right, final));
            return root->state;

            case '*':
            case '+':
            case '?':
                // build an nfa that links to a new state (root): left-->root (or final in case of ?)
                temp = print_nfa(root->left, (IType) (root->type=='?'?final:root->state));
                // create two epsilon transitions one to the nfa above and one to final
                printf("(%d, ε, %d)\n", root->state, temp);
                printf("(%d, ε, %d)\n", root->state, final);
                if (root->type == '+')
                    return temp; // return the start state of the nfa as the start state into this
                else
                    return root->state; // return root as the start state into this

            case CHAR: // create a transition from this state (root) to final
                printf("(%d, %d, %d)\n", root->state, root->ch, final);
                return root->state;

            case ANY:
                printf("(%d, ANY, %d)\n", root->state, final);
                return root->state;

            case SET:
                printf("(%d, [%s], %d)\n", root->state, root->charset, final);
                return root->state;

            default:   break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct Node *root;
    IType       final, start;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: %s regex\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    regex = argv[1];

    root = parse(MAX_PREC, NULL);
    start = print_nfa(root, final = state++);
    printf("start = %d, final = %d\n", start, final);
    return 0;
}
```

This approach combines two algorithms: Vaughan Pratt’s top-down operator
precedence parsing scheme as it is described in Nystrom's book "Crafting Interpreters" chapter 17 and the Thompson NFA algorithm as it is presented in the inspiring article "Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast" ([https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/regexp1.html)). As I did not find the combination of the two approaches in one program, I decided to share what I came up with even if the original question is 5 years old.